# How put text scrollbar in Flash (actionscript 3) in specific line?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have used the Flash UIScrollbar component to scroll my texts which i have imported externally.  Is it possible manipulate the scrollbar to put it in specific line of text? In default the scrollbar placed at the beginning of the text, but I want to it placed at the end or middle or specific line of text.

Answer (score 0):

> scrollPosition : Number Gets or sets the current scroll position and
>   updates the position of the thumb.

example:
`myScrollBar.scrollPosition = 45;`

Source:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ScrollBar.html

Comment: Thanks, I used this code but it made no difference. Could you please tell me how use this. My UIScrollbar instance name is myScrollBar and exactly use above code. My text is imported externally.

Comment: Sorry, anything further and I'd be coding AS3 again just like I was in the 2000's. You should check out Colin Moock's Lost ActionScript Weekend, free on AdobeTV.